# Why does ESP8266 flash write sometimes takes long time?

Tags: performance, flash, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 Nodemcu v0.9 board as referenced by [this blog](http://blog.squix.ch/2015/02/esp8266-nodemcu-dev-kit-review.html).
To program Arduino/ESP8266 sketches I use "[esptool.py](https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool)" using
command line:

```
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 --baud 115200 write_flash 0x000000 MySketch.cpp.bin
```

Sometimes the flash write completes very quickly (in less than 10 seconds),
and sometimes the takes a few minutes. The image size is about 300KBytes.

Is there any way to ensure the flash write is consistently speedy? What
may be the root cause of this difference?

**More info**: Noted a few times that if the image write to flash is the first
time after I have kept the 8266 powered off and disconnected for some time
then often the write is quick. I have not yet determined how much this
time is, but could be more than ten minutes at least. All the subsequent
writes after the first time write are slow.

**More info**: The flash write speed is consistently fast when I use the
Windows based "Nodemcu Firmware Programmer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the version of "esptool" that I had earlier may have something
to do with the slow flash write. Using the version downloaded from [here](https://github.com/themadinventor/)
the flash write/update seems to perform consistently at higher speeds.